# How to store the twitter type ahead first menu item into the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-typeahead

I am using the twitter type ahead for my search box. There is a search button. whenever the user enter the search text and click on search button I want to get the first object and navigate depending on my conditions present inside the that object.
How can I implement this functionality?

```
   <script>
      $(function () {
          var searches = new Bloodhound({
              datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
              queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
              remote: '/home/suggest?q=%QUERY&fuzzy=false'
          });

          searches.initialize();

      $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
          name: 'search-result',
          displayKey: 'Name',
          source: searches.ttAdapter(),
          templates: {
              suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><strong>{{Name}}</strong><div>')
          }
  }).on('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum) {
          console.log(obj);
          console.log(datum);
      });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you show what you have stared so far? some `code` you have started.

Comment: @AlvinMagalona I have updated the question with the code I have used. You can check now.

Comment: Base on the document, the correct event should be `typeahead:select` instead.

Comment: @AlvinMagalona No Thats not working for me.

Comment: which version of typeahead are you using ?